# Creating an SaaS application that automates signup?

Tags: saas

I'm looking for some guidance on my research to building an SaaS. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999888/how-to-create-an-saas-application) seems to be related, but I'm wondering if this software Rackspace has called [rBuilder](http://wiki.rpath.com/wiki/rBuilder) is what I would be looking for to automate the process of creating an instance of the software with a unique IP address and domain name.

Also, for an application similar to Shopify, does the application work like Facebook where it serves up different information based on the account, or is it better to have separate installs of the software like WordPress, but on a server that you maintain?

Comment: Good question! Take a look at this list -> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=saas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, there are various levels of Multi-tenancy [level1 through level4], among them, the purest form of multi-tenancy [Level4] is to have a single code base to cater to the needs of different customers [tenant's].

In this case, you will be required to maintain all of the configuration metadata within your code base to ensure that each tenant has the capability to customize the application the way they wanted to.

Having a single codebase is very clean, easier to maintain, easy to patch, easy to onboard new customers etc...

Hence, kindly note that you have to decide on the time and expense that you have budgeted for the application that you have planned to as the purest form of multi-tenancy does require some  more additional thought process.

You can consult some articles like [this](http://blogs.forrester.com/john_r_rymer/12-03-20-understanding_clouds_multitenancy) and also google on the pros and con's of having the purest form of multi-tenancy vs on-premise model or virtualized model of multi-tenancy.

Also read more from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multitenantsaas/)

Comment: Thanks! Lots of concepts here I haven't heard of that I should research. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.