# Implementation of SAAS in ZEND framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, saas, multi-tenant

I have to create a multi tenant architecture in Zend using SAAS.

I got one idea to implement in 3 step Layout: as Wrapper, Nested Layout & View. It is a much interesting method I felt.

Could any one help me out with some more ideas in how to implement SAAS in Zend frame work.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Perhaps this question may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999888/how-to-create-an-saas-application

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have developed a MultiTenant Site using Zend Framework in SaaS Model. And written a Blog with the main things which we need to consider. Check it: [SaaS application development using PHP in Zend Framework](http://advancedphpsolutions.com/blog/zend-framework/saas-application-development-using-php-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: Please review the [FAQ#promotion] on self-promotion; StackOverflow is not a place to boost your Google ranking and you are running the danger of being flagged for spam.

Comment: And also, your comment does not come with an example that helps out finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is going to be huge and many customers with huge amount of data each customer, i recommend you to use SaaS multi-tenant architecture where each tenant have separate db. you can get more info here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gianpaolo/archive/2006/03/06/544354.aspx

read this article depecting how to use multiple db in zend framework from coding point of view
http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework